# NetworkManager does not detect when cable is connected or disconnected

Tags: fedora, drivers, networkmanager, ethernet

On my Fedora 21 64bit Gnome 3.14.3 install, I have noticed that the NeworkManager always connects to the wired connection, even if the cable is not connected:

[image]

However, the driver (or something) does know whether or not it is connected - I can see this with `watch "dmesg | tail -10"`:

```
[ 7349.552202] atl1c 0000:07:00.0: atl1c: enp7s0 NIC Link is Down
[ 7373.496359] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): enp7s0: link is not ready
[ 7376.271449] atl1c 0000:07:00.0: atl1c: enp7s0 NIC Link is Up<100 Mbps Full Duplex>
[ 7376.271482] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp7s0: link becomes ready
[ 7553.088393] atl1c 0000:07:00.0: atl1c: enp7s0 NIC Link is Down
[ 7597.096174] atl1c 0000:07:00.0: atl1c: enp7s0 NIC Link is Up<100 Mbps Full Duplex>
[ 7620.983378] atl1c 0000:07:00.0: atl1c: enp7s0 NIC Link is Down
[ 7622.556874] atl1c 0000:07:00.0: atl1c: enp7s0 NIC Link is Up<100 Mbps Full Duplex>
```

This causes issues when the cable has unplugged, but it still thinks it is connected to the internet, and trys to sync or connect and fails.

- `lspci -v`

  ```
  07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR8152 v2.0 Fast Ethernet (rev c1)
      Subsystem: Lenovo Device 3979
      Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 29
      Memory at e0500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
      I/O ports at 2000 [size=128]
      Capabilities: <access denied>
      Kernel driver in use: atl1c
      Kernel modules: atl1c
  ```
- `ifconfig`:

  ```
  enp7s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
          inet 192.168.1.22  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
          inet6 fe80::de0e:a1ff:fed1:d12b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
          ether dc:0e:a1:d1:d1:2b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
          RX packets 111875  bytes 67103677 (63.9 MiB)
          RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
          TX packets 87152  bytes 7793021 (7.4 MiB)
          TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 13  collisions 0

  lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
          inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
          inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
          loop  txqueuelen 0  (Local Loopback)
          RX packets 3669  bytes 880913 (860.2 KiB)
          RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
          TX packets 3669  bytes 880913 (860.2 KiB)
          TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
  ```
- `sudo yum list installed NetworkManager*`

  ```
  Installed Packages
  NetworkManager.x86_64                                                        1:0.9.10.1-1.4.20150115git.fc21                                @updates                    
  NetworkManager-adsl.x86_64                                                   1:0.9.10.1-1.4.20150115git.fc21                                @updates                    
  NetworkManager-bluetooth.x86_64                                              1:0.9.10.1-1.4.20150115git.fc21                                @updates                    
  NetworkManager-config-connectivity-fedora.x86_64                             1:0.9.10.1-1.4.20150115git.fc21                                @updates                    
  NetworkManager-config-server.x86_64                                          1:0.9.10.1-1.4.20150115git.fc21                                @updates                    
  NetworkManager-devel.x86_64                                                  1:0.9.10.1-1.4.20150115git.fc21                                @updates                    
  NetworkManager-glib.x86_64                                                   1:0.9.10.1-1.4.20150115git.fc21                                @updates                    
  NetworkManager-glib-devel.x86_64                                             1:0.9.10.1-1.4.20150115git.fc21                                @updates                    
  NetworkManager-iodine.x86_64                                                 0.0.4-4.fc21                                                   @fedora                     
  NetworkManager-iodine-gnome.x86_64                                           0.0.4-4.fc21                                                   @fedora                     
  NetworkManager-l2tp.x86_64                                                   0.9.8.7-3.fc21                                                 @fedora                     
  NetworkManager-openconnect.x86_64                                            0.9.8.6-2.fc21                                                 @updates                    
  NetworkManager-openswan.x86_64                                               0.9.8.4-4.fc21                                                 @fedora                     
  NetworkManager-openswan-gnome.x86_64                                         0.9.8.4-4.fc21                                                 @fedora                     
  NetworkManager-openvpn.x86_64                                                1:0.9.9.0-3.git20140128.fc21                                   @koji-override-0/$releasever
  NetworkManager-openvpn-gnome.x86_64                                          1:0.9.9.0-3.git20140128.fc21                                   @koji-override-0/$releasever
  NetworkManager-pptp.x86_64                                                   1:0.9.8.2-6.fc21                                               @koji-override-0/$releasever
  NetworkManager-pptp-gnome.x86_64                                             1:0.9.8.2-6.fc21                                               @koji-override-0/$releasever
  NetworkManager-ssh.x86_64                                                    0.9.3-0.3.20140601git9d834f2.fc21                              @fedora                     
  NetworkManager-ssh-gnome.x86_64                                              0.9.3-0.3.20140601git9d834f2.fc21                              @fedora                     
  NetworkManager-tui.x86_64                                                    1:0.9.10.1-1.4.20150115git.fc21                                @updates                    
  NetworkManager-vpnc.x86_64                                                   1:0.9.9.0-6.git20140428.fc21                                   @koji-override-0/$releasever
  NetworkManager-vpnc-gnome.x86_64                                             1:0.9.9.0-6.git20140428.fc21                                   @koji-override-0/$releasever
  NetworkManager-wifi.x86_64                                                   1:0.9.10.1-1.4.20150115git.fc21                                @updates                    
  NetworkManager-wwan.x86_64                                                   1:0.9.10.1-1.4.20150115git.fc21                                @updates
  ```

  - `modinfo atl1c`

    ```
    filename:       /lib/modules/3.17.8-300.fc21.x86_64/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/atl1c/atl1c.ko.xz
    version:        1.0.1.1-NAPI
    license:        GPL
    description:    Qualcom Atheros 100/1000M Ethernet Network Driver
    author:         Qualcomm Atheros Inc., <nic-devel@qualcomm.com>
    author:         Jie Yang
    srcversion:     4333D8ADEE755DD5ABDF0B8
    alias:          pci:v00001969d00001083sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
    alias:          pci:v00001969d00001073sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
    alias:          pci:v00001969d00002062sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
    alias:          pci:v00001969d00002060sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
    alias:          pci:v00001969d00001062sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
    alias:          pci:v00001969d00001063sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
    depends:        
    intree:         Y
    vermagic:       3.17.8-300.fc21.x86_64 SMP mod_unload 
    signer:         Fedora kernel signing key
    sig_key:        F4:8F:FC:A3:C9:62:D6:47:0F:1A:63:E0:32:D1:F5:F1:93:2A:03:6A
    sig_hashalgo:   sha256
    ```

If this is a bug, is it NetworkManager or something else? I had no issues with this under Fedora 19 with the same driver (which seems to be the same version in the latest kernel in its backup).

Comment: i guess it is a bug of networkmanager .

Comment: Following the dupe of http://askubuntu.com/questions/588417/what-is-the-difference-between-eth0-p4p1 I did the the `net.ifnames=0 biosdevname=0` in grub.cfg, so the interface name in `ifconfig` is now `eth0` not `enp7s0` - made no difference :)

Comment: Same issue on new Lenovo B590 (with Realtek  RTL8111/8168/8411 card) - will report as bug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually got around to putting together [a bug report](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1202913), and was told that removing the `NetworkManager-config-server` package would solve it - so I did:

```
sudo yum autoremove NetworkManager-config-server
```

Then I rebooted, and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

on Fedora32 I did

```
sudo dnf remove NetworkManager-config-connectivity-fedora
```

rebooted and the issue was gone